# Handling multiple HTTP requests from one source (e.g. a hacker)

Tags: php, apache

I have a script to handle http requests. I'm trying to think of some of the security issues I might have with it. My biggest concern at the moment is how I can manage multiple requests from the same source over and over. For instance someone trying to shut down my system.

Do I need to be concerned or will Apache handle this issue. If not what is the best approach to take using php?

Comment: In other words, you're looking for [(D)DoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) prevention?

Comment: Do you mean blocking someone if he tries DOSing your server?

Comment: yes - although that sounds like it would be handled by apache, right?

Comment: Yup, do it at server level. This is a non-concern for PHP. See answer of splicer.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [mod_evasive](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?page_id=442) Apache module. Also, the Apache documentation has some [good tips](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/misc/security_tips.html#dos).

Answer (score 3):

IMHO security has always to be considered from different viewpoints and at different levels.

From what you've described and what I think you're trying to achieve (Denial Of Service Attack countermesure), tough, it's my belief that your best bet would be that of dealing with requests at a lower level (IE packet filtering) than where apache operates. With PHP alone you can definitely perform other security checks, but most likely not do much (if anything) against a DOS Attack.

Comment: Blimey! I'll have a look into it. Thanks